I am trying to click on cookie accept button , but it's not working
I have this website : https://my.cassanova.com/login.html which I'm trying to login into. When opening the browser, the classical cookie banner appears, so I tried to program the click on the accept button (xpath = //*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"] ), but to no avail (webdriver just runs out of time). Any suggestions?
